# What text rendering library does Chrome use on Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome

Are they using `freetype` or `xfonts` or `cairo` or something else? Maybe their own made library? I am thinking to use the same library in my program as well. I think what Google uses will be well maintained for long time.

Comment: They don't use font packages. They use fonts. oO ?

Comment: @DanFromGermany, do you know what font rendering is?

Comment: sorry I missunderstood at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer is not correct. Under the hood, Skia uses Uniscribe on Windows, HarfBuzz on Linux + ChromeOS, and CoreText on the Mac. (Actually it's possible at this point, much of the Uniscribe and CoreText code has also been replaced with HarfBuzz for consistency.) Skia is used only to draw glyphs after the the shaping/layout code has done its job.

https://skia.org/docs/user/tips/ : "Skia does not shape text. Skia provides interfaces to draw glyphs, but does not implement a text shaper. Skia’s client’s often use HarfBuzz to generate the glyphs and their positions, including kerning."

Comment: Can you say a bit more? I looked into Harfbuzz and it doesn't do everything. No bidi, different font properties,  line breaking, hyphenation, justification, font selection, language discovery. How are they doing that part?

Comment: @Chris you're right, in a browser you can't just lay out bidi text in the text engine, because the entire page layout algorithm has to respond to text layout direction. It looks like this is what Chrome is using: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/layoutNg-2/

Answer (score 1):

> Chrome uses Skia for nearly all graphics operations, including text
>   rendering. GDI is for the most part only used for native theme
>   rendering; new code should use Skia.

http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/graphics-and-skia

> Skia is a complete 2D graphic library for drawing Text, Geometries, and Images.

Skia Project Page:

http://code.google.com/p/skia/